# Как в .Net Core (c#) скрывать методы базового класса

Tags: c#, наследование, .net-core, сокрытие-функций

Сокрытие методов. Делаю библиотеку классов (.net core).
Суть в следующем. У меня есть базовый класс в котором определены некоторые методы. Мне нужно чтобы в дочернем классе эти методы скрывались и были недоступны.

Когда я делал обычную библиотеку классов, я просто писал private new. Но с net core не работает.

В базовом A классе я пишу

```
public void Method(){//тело метода}
```

В дочернем B классе пишу

```
private new void Method(){//тело метода}
```

Затем в консольном приложении в переменной класса B мне доступен этот метод и при выполнении программы он отрабатывает метод базового класса.

Как мне скрыть методы?
Не смог найти такой вопрос на форуме.

Comment: Мне кажется у вас чуть неверное понимание ООП...

Comment: Более правильный подход показать что наследник что-то не умеет - перегрузить метод и выбросить в нем исключение, например `NotSupportedException`

Comment: Подобная необходимость может свидетельствовать об архитектурных проблемах (некорректно спроектированная иерархия классов).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такое "скрытие" не работает ни в обычном .NET, и в .NET Core.

Методы, объявленные в базовом классе, скрыть нельзя. Если бы было можно - то объект-наследник все равно можно было бы привести к базовому классу и вызвать у него "скрытый" метод.

Следующий код работает компилируется без ошибок и в Core, и в не .Core версиях:

```
class A
{
    public void Method(){ }
}

class B : A
{
    private new void Method(){  }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.Method(); // вызывается A.Method по ссылке на B

        A a = new B();
        a.Method(); // вызывается A.Method по ссылке типа A на объект типа B
    }
}
```

Comment: Получается если я захочу чтобы в дочернем классе не использовались методы то все, что я могу это переопредилить их на пустые и в XML комментариях предупредить, чтобы никто их не использовал?

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я нашел решение свое проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы ищите модификатор `internal` который ограничивает область видимости сборкой в которой объявлен класс. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

`internal` методы публичны для классов внутри библиотеки, но из консольного приложения, использующего эту библиотеку, метод доступен не будет.

Comment: Это ключевое слово, а не атрибут и ТС ищет очевидно не это.

Comment: @Maxwell Очевидное не очевидно.